# While deploying under release I get "LinkAssemblies failed" error

Tags: xamarin.forms

Just created a new project, Haven't touched anything yet except create some custom classes. Haven't touched the UI part, tried to deploy in release and I get this error:

```
The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Reference to metadata item 'System.Void Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout::AddDrawerListener(Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout/IDrawerListener)' (defined in 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') from 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be resolved. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout::AddDrawerListener(Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout/IDrawerListener)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() TakeAm.Droid    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   1571
```

I really don't know what I've done wrong I've tried changing the target and compile versions to the latest versions but still nothing. My Forms Nuget is Updated also.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug.

[Bug 48014 - blank xaml app (xamarin.forms portable) release build fails](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=48014%20(i've%20left%20full%20link%20address)

The bug was fixed in an alpha release:

> **Jose Gallardo 2016-12-02 19:54:01 UTC**
>   .../...
>   We're going to replace the old cross-platform templates with a new set of templates where this issue is fixed.
>   That new version will be out in the next XVS 4.3 preview (which will be available in the Alpha channel probably next week).

To add to my answer, there's other issues that may need to be addressed with that update.

Taken from [Xamarin Android no longer builds release after Xamarin Update](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77662/xamarin-android-no-longer-builds-release-after-xamarin-update?), [John Miller](https://forums.xamarin.com/profile/37696/JohnMiller):

> Check that you have the following installed:
>
> XVS 4.2.0.703
>
> Android SDK Tools 25.2.2
>    Android Platform-tools 24.0.3
>    Android
>   Build-tools 24.0.3
>    Android support repository 38
>
> Java 1.8 (8u101) 64 bit (Remove Java 1.7 if you have it, see more info
>   here:
>   https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_7/xamarin.android_7.0/)
>
> Make sure you have API 23 or 24 installed to compile the Android
>   project against.